# Find the number of ordered triples of subsets of $S$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, contest-math

> Let $S = \{1, 2, 3,...., n\}$. Find the number of ordered triples $(A,B,C)$ of subsets of $S$ such that $A \subseteq B$ and $A \cup B \cup C = S$.

I'm not sure how to approach this question and saw a similar question where the solution involved something along the lines of dividing $S$ into three parts $A_1, A_2, A_3$ such that $A = A_1$, $B = A_1 \cup A_2$, $C = A_3$ and $S = A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3$ but I didn't really understand it. Please help.

Comment: Well...choose $B$.  then $A$ can be any subset of $B$ and $C$ can be any superset of $B^c$.  Work it out along these lines for small $n$ until you see the general pattern.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Notice that since $A\subseteq B$, saying that $A\cup B\cup C=S$ really just amounts to saying that $B\cup C=S$. In other words, $C$ has to contain all of $S\setminus B$, and in addition it can contain any subset of $B$. And $A$, of course, can be any subset of $B$.

- If $|B|=k$, how many possibilities are there for $A$?
- If $|B|=k$, how many possibilities are there for $C$?
- How many $B\subseteq S$ are there with $|B|=k$?

Now put the those three pieces together to get an answer expressed as a summation. This summation has a nice closed form. If you don’t see what it is, calculate its value for $n=1,2$, and $3$; from those you should be able to guess the closed form, and that form may suggest the theorem that you can use to get it directly from the summation.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Draw a Venn diagram of sets $A, B, C$ (say, circles) so that $A$ is inside $B$, and $C$ intersects both $A$ and $B\setminus A$ (but doesn't completely contain either). Ignore the outside of $A\cup B\cup C=B\cup C$. How many different non-intersecting regions does this partition $S=B\cup C$ into? Now note that every element of $S$ belongs to exactly $1$ of those non-intersecting regions, and these choices are independent of each other.

> There are $5$ non-intersecting regions: $A\cap C$, $A\setminus C=A\cap\overline{C}$, $(B\setminus A)\cap C=\overline{A}\cap B\cap C$, $(B\setminus A)\setminus C=\overline{A}\cap B\cap \overline{C}$, and $C\setminus B=\overline{B}\cap C$. So, there are $5$ choices for the location of every one of the $n$ elements, so the total number of choices is $5^n$.